# IE7 not running JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

html:

```
<body>
    <script>
        alert('hello1');
    </script>
    <script src="/js/ie.js"></script>
</body>
```

ie.js:

```
alert('hello2');
```

IE7 only alerts `hello1`, it does not alert `hello2`. It works in IE8 for example. Developing on localhost through MS own VM modern.ie images.

Comment: With apologies, I believe this is just an error in your testing. IE7 has no problem loading and running JavaScript.

Comment: no problem with your code tested on ie7 , try to remove the slash from the beginning of src attribute

Comment: @AnasOmar The file is being loaded correctly according to developer tools so I doubt it's that. Nevertheless I tried, no change.

Comment: @KarlMorrison did u try the console.log ??

Comment: @AnasOmar Exactly the same outcome, works in IE8 but not in IE7!